# How to populate and edit a std::array of maps

Tags: c++, arrays, stdvector, stdmap, stdarray

I have an array of maps:

```
std::array<std::map<double, double>, 8> freqMap;
```

When populating this I need to add entries to the map at different array indices. I know I can create 8 different maps, populate them, and then add them to the array, but is it possible to keep appending entries to the maps directly in the array?

For example, how would I go about adding a map entries of `key` 5.0, `val` 3.3 to array index 2, and then add another entry to array index 3, and then append another entry to index 2 again and so on.

I can also use `std::vector` of maps, but still don't see a way to add entries this way.

Here is an example. I'm reading the data from a file and want to update my data structure directly:

```
while (fin >> arrayIdx >> key>> val)
    freqMaps[arrayIdx] = ??
```

Comment: Arrays are fixed size. If you want to append to it then you should use a `std::vector` instead. To add entries, just `push_back`.

Comment: So long as this isn't `const` you can add to the inner maps without any issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do:

```cpp
while (fin >> arrayIdx >> key>> val)
  freqMaps[arrayIdx][key] = val;
```

> For example, how would I go about adding a map entries of key 5.0, val 3.3 to array index 2

```
freqMaps[2][5.0] = 3.3;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Yf18Tx).

Also, note that using `double` as keys in a `std::map` is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a braced init list:

```
while (fin >> arrayIdx >> key >> val)
    freqMap.at(arrayIdx) = {{key, val}};
```

Or

```
while (fin >> arrayIdx >> key >> val)
    freqMap[arrayIdx] = {{key, val}};
```

Provided that `arrayIdx` is smaller than 8 of course, otherwise you are accessing the array out of its bounds, I would prefer the first method using `at` because in case of bad access, an exception is thrown, which gives you nicer error handling options.

To access a specific value given the key, let's say you want to print it:

```
std::cout << freqMap.at(arrayIdx).at(key);
```

Or to cycle through the whole array:

```
for (auto& a : freqMap)
{
    for (auto& m : a)
    {
        std::cout << m.first << m.second;
    }
}
```

[Live sample](https://godbolt.org/z/1rjnfn)

If you use C++17 or later the cycle method provided in [@cigien's demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63641983/6865932) is nicer than using `first` and `second` nodes.